# I need to create a 3d array that is populated with random doubles that will then iterate through and tell me the address of each number

Tags: arrays, memory-address

I am trying to create a 3D array that auto populates with random doubles. After I need to print out the address of each number in the 3d array. This code answers my issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   double myArray[4][2][3];
   srand(time(NULL));
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                myArray[i][j][k] =  (((double)rand())/RAND_MAX)*49;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                printf("Address(%p),myArray[%zu][%zu][%zu] = %lf\n",&myArray[i][j][k],i,j,k,myArray[i][j][k]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it working? If not, does it show any error?

Comment: I edited it to include those. It doesn't work and it throws an error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: This looks much better! But still can't help you if you don't publish the error

Comment: There is no error. It does exactly as it was meant to do error free